# VMware Fusion virtualization - Do dedicated graphics and disk RPM make much difference?

Tags: hardware, vmware, virtualization

How much difference does dedicated graphics and HDD speed matter when using virtual machines?

For the last year I have been using a MacBook Pro 15" with the following specs with great success.

- Core i7
- 8 GB RAM
- 7200 RPM HDD
- Dedicated Graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB)

I do a good deal of development in Windows so I use VMware Fusion with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 as guest operating systems. Everything has worked really well.

Well, recently my wife's MacBook died and we got a replacement MacBook Pro 13" with the following specs

- Core i7
- 8 GB RAM
- 5400 RPM HDD
- Integrated graphics (Intel)

Since the processor and RAM are the same I thought I might benefit from the smaller form factor of the 13" MacBook (can use external monitor when at home) and my wife could use the power of the dedicated graphics for video editing and the like.

So that brings me to my question. How much will a slower HDD and non-dedicated graphics card effect my virtual machine performance? I don't play any games so I never thought I made use of the dedicated graphics card. I don't know if it actually helped with the VM or not. What about the Disk Drive speed? Does this play a major factor? I really never noticed any swapping when using VMWare Fusion. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference will be negligable. You won't notice the graphics at all, and will *barely* notice the difference in speed from the hard drive.

Solid state disks are dropping in price all the time, if you do feel like the drive is "slow" down the track you can purchase an SSD and upgrade it yourself fairly easily without voiding your warranty. ([OWC](http://www.macsales.com/) sell DIY SSD upgrade kits for example)